# Laravel informa que a pagina não foi encontrada: 404 na rota master/test

Tags: mysql, laravel, mysqli, sql-update

Como fazer esse update funcionar? Abaixo código das páginas.

## Form_edit.php

```
<form role="form">
    <div class="box-body">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Name</label>
            <input type="text" 
                    class="form-control" 
                    name="name_masters"
                    id="name_masters"
                    placeholder="Enter masters name">
        </div>                
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email_masters">Email address</label>
            <input type="email" 
                name="email_masters"
                id="email_masters"
                class="form-control" 
                placeholder="Enter masters email">
        </div>
        <div class="box-footer">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

## alterar.blade.php

```
<form action="{{route('master.update', 'test')}}" method="post">                 
    {{method_field('patch')}}
    {{csrf_field()}}
    <div class="modal-body">
        <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value="">
        @include('Masters.form_edit')
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save Changes</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

## test.blade.php

```
{{$user->email}}
```

## MasterController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use \App\Master;
use \App\user;
use Gate;

class MasterController extends Controller
{

  public function update(Request $request)
    {

        $master = Master::findOrFail($request->id_master);
        $master->update($request->all());       
        return back();
    }
}
?>
```

## Web.php

```
Route::post('master', function () { })->name('master.update');
```

Comment: eu recomenod reformular melhor a pergunta e o titulo, e aproveitando da onde vem esse `id_master`

Comment: Você está utilizando route no seu form action, você tem uma rota no arquivo routes com este nome, algo do tipo Route::post('master/update', function () {  })->name('master.update');

Comment: Otimo. Esse e um problema e eu resolvi agora. Quanto ao Route, obrigado. Mas tem sim. Obrigado irmaos por seu tempo!

Comment: `{{method_field('patch')}}` eu acho que é só retirar isso, porque esta mudando o verbo? Se não coloque a rota e melhora a pergunta.

Comment: Isso mesmo, vou colocar a rota. Blz irmao.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comece alterando sua rota para que possa chegar no seu controller e parar de exibir o 404 (Lembrando que 404 é página não encontrada):

Web.php

```
Route::post('master', "MasterController@update")->name('master.update');
```